# C++ Map Initialize object using non-default constructor

Tags: c++

In C++ suppose I have an unordered map defined as follows:

```
unordered_map<int, MyClass> my_map;
auto my_class = my_map[1];
```

In the above code if 1 is not present as key in my_map it will initialize MyClass with default constructor and return. But is there a way to use non-default constructor of MyClass for initialization?

Comment: Since sets are a *key-only* your declaration of `my_set` is invalid. Do you mean to use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead?

Comment: What about `my_set[1] = MyClass(...);`? This may involve a copy. If that's not intended it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: And if you mean `std::unordered_map`, then no there's no other way than to have a default constructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I meant std::unordered_map.

Comment: You should create a method getMyMap(key, ...) which returns my_map[key] and creates it right before using the parameters "..." for construction. Otherwise I see no other way. Moreover I would not advise to take the habit to using `operator []` for maps, because if you make an error in your algorithm (retrieving a non existing key you thought existed) it will compile and run and you will not know why you get the wrong result.

Answer (score 9):

You're right that `operator[]` needs the value type to be default-constructible.

[`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) does not:

```
std::unordered_map<int, MyClass> my_map;
// Populate the map here

// Get element with key "1", creating a new one
// from the given value if it doesn't already exist
auto result = my_map.insert({1, <your value here>});
```

This gives you a pair containing an iterator to the element (whether created new, or already present), and a boolean (telling you which was the case).

So:

```
auto& my_class = *result.first;
const bool was_inserted = result.second;
```

Now you can do whatever you like with this information. Often you won't even care about `result.second` and can just ignore it.

For more complex value types you can play around with `emplace`, which is like `insert` but, um, better. Say you really don't want the value to be constructed if it won't be used, and you have C++17:

```
auto result = my_map.try_emplace(1, <your value's ctor args here here>);
```

If you don't care (or don't have C++17):

```
auto result = my_map.emplace(1, <your value>);
```

This is still better than `insert` as it can move the value into the map, rather than copying it.

Ultimately, and if you don't even want to unnecessarily produce your ctor args, you can always just do a `find` first, but it's nice to try to avoid that, as the insertion operation itself will be doing a find too.

Comment: "you can always do a find first"  - or use `try_emplace` instead, if C++17 available. That would make the (in my eyes at least) so far best answer complete...

Comment: @Aconcagua You still have to have all your ctor args ready to go, which may or may not be a problem. Could be good though

Comment: @Aconcagua At the very least it's a drop-in replacement for the piecewise approach

Comment: If value-type construction is expensive, but arguments are cheap we spare the preceding lookup with find. And as the drop-in is simpler than the piece-wise stuff (well, I might now cite your own words from comment to Scheff's answer)...

Comment: Hm, hope I'm not getting pedantic, but "equivalently" is not correct in detail: While the element "may be created even if there already is[...]" with the former, it won*t be with the latter...

Comment: @Aconcagua Oh, I see, that's _not_ true for the piecewise `emplace` - ok, thanks! Wow, piecewise `emplace` is kind of useless then, no? At least in this sense

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a `struct T`:

```
struct T {
  int i1, i2;
  // no default constructor
  explicit T(int i1, int i2): i1(i1), i2(i2) { }
};
```

With a default constructor it's quite easy:

```
aMap[123] = T(1, 23);
```

The `operator[]` grants that a non-existing entry is created on demand (but for this it needs the default constructor of the mapped type).

---

If the class of `mapped_type` doesn't provide a default constructor OP's intention can be matched by a simple combination of [`std::unordered_map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and [`std::unordered_map::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) (or just only the latter with check of success).

(This part was inserted later as A Lightness Races in Orbit pointed out that I skipped this simple solution and directly moved to the more complicated.) He wrote an [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52291049/7478597) concerning this. As it is lacking a demonstrational [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I took mine and adapted it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct T {
  int i1, i2;
  // no default constructor
  explicit T(int i1, int i2): i1(i1), i2(i2)
  {
    std::cout << "T::T(" << i1 << ", " << i2 << ")\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  typedef std::unordered_map<int, T> Map;
  Map aMap;
  //aMap[123] = T(1, 23); doesn't work without default constructor.
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    Map::key_type key = 123;
    Map::iterator iter = aMap.find(key);
    if (iter == aMap.end()) {
      std::pair<Map::iterator, bool> ret
        = aMap.insert(Map::value_type(key, T(1 + i, 23)));
      if (ret.second) std::cout << "Insertion done.\n";
      else std::cout << "Insertion failed! Key " << key << " already there.\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "Key " << key << " found.\n";
    }
  }
  for (const auto &entry : aMap) {
    std::cout << entry.first << " -> (" << entry.second.i1 << ", " << entry.second.i2 << ")\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
T::T(1, 23)
Insertion done.
Key 123 found.
123 -> (1, 23)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7f3a30815953abc)</kbd>

---

If the mapped type does lack a copy constructor as well then it's still solvable using [`std::unordered_map::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) (again with or without pre-check with [`std::unordered_map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)):

```
aMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
  std::forward_as_tuple(123),
  std::forward_as_tuple(1, 23));
```

The adapted sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct T {
  int i1, i2;
  // no default constructor
  explicit T(int i1, int i2): i1(i1), i2(i2)
  {
    std::cout << "T::T(" << i1 << ", " << i2 << ")\n";
  }
  // copy constructor and copy assignment disabled
  T(const T&) = delete;
  T& operator=(const T&);
};

int main()
{
  typedef std::unordered_map<int, T> Map;
  Map aMap;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    Map::key_type key = 123;
    Map::iterator iter = aMap.find(key);
    if (iter == aMap.end()) {
      std::pair<Map::iterator, bool> ret
        = aMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple(key),
          std::forward_as_tuple(1 + i, 23));
      if (ret.second) std::cout << "Insertion done.\n";
      else std::cout << "Insertion failed! Key " << key << " already there.\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "Key " << key << " found.\n";
    }
  }
  for (const auto &entry : aMap) {
    std::cout << entry.first << " -> (" << entry.second.i1 << ", " << entry.second.i2 << ")\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
T::T(1, 23)
Insertion done.
Key 123 found.
123 -> (1, 23)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54f46b618ca0a239)</kbd>

As Aconcagua mentioned in comment, without the pre-checking `find()`, the `emplace()` might construct the mapped value even if the insertion will fail.

The doc. of [`std::unordered_map::emplace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) on cppreference mentions this:

> The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately.

---

As Jarod42 mentioned, [`std::unordered_map::try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) is an alternative in C++17 worth to be mentioned as

> Unlike insert or emplace, these functions do not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen, which makes it easy to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<foo>>`. In addition, `try_emplace` treats the key and the arguments to the `mapped_type` separately, unlike emplace, which requires the arguments to construct a `value_type` (that is, a `std::pair`)

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right. (I focused on the "non-default constructible" as I didn't agree with SomeProgrammerDude's comment but I wanted to check it out before realizing some wrong imagination of mine.) However, I edit the answer.

Comment: (Adjustment of previous, deleted comment): emplace [*might*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) construct the MyClass element even if existing; if constructing is a cheap operation, this might be fine, if it is expensive, we might prefer something like `auto i = find; auto mc = i != end ? *i : *(emplace().first);`...

Comment: For these types, this seems like an overcomplicated solution. Why not just `insert`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are many ways to get stuff into a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. Some of them are quite easy and other a bit more complicated but worth in special situations. The example `struct T` is quite simple for demonstration (and to keep the code as small as possible). `emplace()` has the IMHO big advance of in-place construction and hence worth to be mentioned. (May be, I should've mentioned this fact explicitly.) You might add an alternative answer showing how simple it would be with an `insert()`. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I did. Generally speaking you should start with the simple solution (especially when teaching), and only get complicated when it's needed. Your code will be clearer and more maintainable that way.

Comment: Your hint is wrong (always `aMap.end()` instead of `aMap.lower_bound(key)`) but then checking key is already present is more verbose :/. `try_emplace` (C++17) is a good alternative.

Comment: @Jarod42 `lower_bound()`? `lower_bound()` would come in mind when I use a `std::map`. In a `std::unordered_map`, there is no order. (Hence, they called it `unordered_map`. ;-) ) So, `lower_bound` shouldn't be an option (but `find()` hopefully will be even more effective -> O(1) for an `unordered_map` instead of O(ld N).) I'm afraid you commented the wrong answer... ;-)

Comment: Part of my comment is wrong (only apply only to `std::map`). but `hint` for `emplace_hint` is only useful is `hint` represent already present key (which is not the case of `.end()` anyway). So you have two look-up.

Comment: @Jarod42 Got it. Yepp, I didn't care about it. (For my luck, the implementation considers even the case where the hint is wrong.) I will fix it. I translated it wrong from my usual case in `std::map` where it works (in combination with `lower_bound` - here we are). ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I seem to recall hints generally not being very widely used, but I could be remembering wrong or it could have changed

Answer (score 1):

`[]` implements `get_add_if_missing`. Semantically, an overhead-free implementation would be something like:

```
value_type& get_add_if_missing(key_type const& k, auto&& factory) {
    auto b = bucket_for(k);
    auto pos = pos_for(k, b);
    if (pos == b.end()) {
        return b.append(k, factory());
    } else {
        return *pos;
    }
}
```

A full equivalent is not there on the API yet (as of `C++17`), so for now, you need to decide what suboptimality to have based on how expensive it is to creating a temporary `value_type`:

- do an extra lookup (search then insert if missing)
- extra temporary (`insert/emplace` always, covered well in other answers)

An extra lookup version is:

```
final itr = m.find(key);
if (itr == m.end()) {
    // insert or emplace a new element with the constructor of your choice
}
```

The [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) article on cppreference should have enough usage examples for `insert` / `emplace`.

With a tree-based implementation (`std::map`) a zero overhead `get_add_if_missing` emulation is quite possible with `lower_bound` followed by a hint-enabled `insert` / `emplace`.

And finally the good news -- if you can accept [Boost.Intrusive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) (a header-only library) as a dependency, you can build a truly zero-overhead `get_add_if_missing` (no temporaries or repeated hash calculation). An API of the hash map from there is sufficiently detailed for that.

Comment: [`insert` is already "add_if_missing"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert); you don't need to find first

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes, but you don’t usually want to construct a `value_type` unnecessarily, which is not possible with just using the `insert`.

Comment: Okay - it wasn't clear that this is a constraint you meant for the hypothetical `add_if_missing`. Anyway in this case it seems to be of little to no cost in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Anyway.. this, then, combined with my answer, is pretty thorough.

Comment: Nah too complicated they can stand apart :) If you want to just quickly note something about unnecessary construction you can have a +1 :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - just did :-)